# How do I display more than 5 bookmarks in gnome-panel "Places" menu?

Tags: gnome-panel

I found [a thread on the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1066964), but it requires me to change the source of `gnome-panel` and recompile.  Is that really the only option if I want to see more than 5 bookmarks in the "Places" menu?  I have a huge monitor -- it seems funny to only show two bookmarks and push the others into a separate "Bookmarks" sub-menu.

Answer (score 3):

> Is that really the only option if I want to see more than 5 bookmarks in the "Places" menu?

Yes. I'm suffering the same issue. I've posted bugs on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/282842) (marked a dupe of [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/262520)) and [Gnome's Trac](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=549788). I there are multiple BrainStorm threads too.

There are two elegant solutions:

1. Look at the resolution when gnome-panel loads, work out some render geometry based on the current theme and set a soft limit
2. Just use a gconf key-value to have a user-alterable number.

But both solutions require somebody to code them, somebody to accept one patch and then somebody to repackage the new version for Ubuntu... In short, it's a change that isn't going to happen soon (unless somebody steps up and gets something pushed in as a Papercut for Maverick - might be too late even for that)

Manually patching the code to have a higher fixed limit is a pain in the bottom but it does fix the problem and (in fairness) doesn't take all day to do. Just make sure you lock the version of your gnome-panel package so updates don't wipe your changes.

I'll go and poke people upstream and see if anything can be done about this.

Comment: Option 2 looks best. Will see if I can contrib a patch..

Comment: A patch exists upstream on the Gnome bug... It's just not getting applied by Gnome or Ubuntu. Get it sponsored into Ubuntu and the problem is fixed.

Comment: Since I can't comment (yet), I'll have to post an answer.

Just to further Oli's comment, [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1066964) is an ubuntuforums thread on how to patch gnome-menu to support more bookmarks.

Comment: I think this is the forum post I referenced.